# Huawei modem does not work with 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb-modem, 3g

Ubuntu 16.04 does not recognize my `Huawei 15ca` USB modem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: That looks like a problem indeed but what's your question?

Answer (score 11):

This command worked for me. I just needed to execute it once.

```
lsusb
```

Note down vendor and product id. In my case it is `12d1` and `1f01` respectively.

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:038f Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b008 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Then execute this once.

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1f01 -J
```

Comment: from where did you got the `1f01` I don't see it in the above terminal extract

Comment: From the lsusb output. The output I have posted is after executing usb_modeswitch which changes product id to 14db in my case.

Comment: Yes, it worked but how can I run it only once and for al?l

Answer (score 8):

The instructions on how to fix this are slightly different than 14.04.

One of these steps might not be needed, but here is how I got it to work:

```
vi /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

and add this line:

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="15ca", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Then:

```
sudo touch /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:15ca
```

Run this command:

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15ca
```

Now you should see it under available network connections and under lsusb it appears with a different product number:

```
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem/Networkcard
```

You might have to reboot or remove and reinsert the modem a couple of times to get it to work. Also remember to add it into edit connection/add mobile broadband connection.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this, e.g. execute `sudo usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15ca` everytime the modem is connected? I remember this used to work automatically  before 16.04 (after applying a similar fix like yours, of course).

Comment: Yes, there is a way. I am writing an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today. I had 2 computers with Ubuntu 16.04 where the `12d7:1505` modem works well.

I bought another one and it does not work without the

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1506 -J
```

command.

I fixed it with another `udev` rule.

Add `/etc/udev/rules.d/huawei.rules` file with this content:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1505", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1506 -J"
```

Then reboot, or run `sudo udevadm control -R` and insert the modem. You need to wait about 30 seconds for modem to boot, then you can use it.

Comment: solved my problem permanently

Comment: Same here, it was so easy I learnt nothing. :|

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions works on my 16.04. (udev rules worked perfectly on 14.04).

I mean, sometimes this does work, but very rarely. I tested these manual commands

```
usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 15ca -V 12d1 -P 1506 -M "55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

and

```
/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15ca
```

and they do work, but not every time, even, if entered by hand. The device remains listed as "mass storage" in more than half cases.

:(

Therefore I had to use a very dirty solution: I added the latter one to root's crontab to run every 10 seconds. I know it's ridiculous, but I cannot think of anything better in these circumstances. The command will work if the device is listed as mass storage (if it is already turned into a modem, it just exits with a message "No devices in default mode found. Nothing to do. Bye!" so it does not interfere with a properly working modem.

This is stupid, but in case somebody would like to use it, here are my crontab entries:

```
* * * * *           /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15ca  > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 10; /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15ca  > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 20; /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15ca  > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 30; /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15ca  > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 40; /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15ca  > /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * sleep 50; /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -J -v 0x12d1 -p 0x15ca  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The device starts working after either 10 or 20 seconds (if the command has to be run twice - which is most of the cases).

I also added this to my /etc/fstab to prevent an attempt to mount the usb mass storage shortly after inserting. This prevents the "Open files" window which normally shows up when a CD is inserted.

```
/dev/sr0 on /media/username/PLAY\ ONLINE iso9660 noauto
```

(you have to adjust the mounting place according to what the mount command shows after the device is mounted - mine mounts in the PLAY ONLINE folder, which is the name of my mobile provider).

Answer (score 0):

You want to automate this? if you modem plug in you didn't setting again.

first

```
sudo nano /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf
```

copy this code

`# HUAWEI E3131
DefaultVendor=0x12d1
DefaultProduct=0x15ca
TargetVendor=0x12d1
TargetProduct=0x1506
MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000a11062000000000000100000000000000"`

save, and execute this on terminal

`sudo usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf`

and wait a minute, if you modem detected and you can use to connect to the internet, this setting is work.