# USB Modem can't be connected on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

USB modem is detecting in network manager, but clicking on connect button, it keeps on going for few minutes and disconnects thereafter. I thought It was a fault with my computer. But wasn't. I tried with another computer which is installed same operating system(16.04). I use **Prolink PHS600** usb modem. Then, I changed usb modem also (*Huawei Power-Fi E8231*). But same results happent. I think It's a common fault in **Ubuntu 16.04LTS**. How can I fix this.?

Comment: Have same issue with ubuntu 16.10

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/776497/huawei-modem-does-not-work-with-16-04  this works for me