# Huawei USB Modem not working?

Tags: networking, network-manager, usb-modem

I am running ubuntu 17.04 with kde plasma 5 (i think).

When I insert my huawei e303f modem then it gets detected in network manger GUI.
I created a new profile by clicking on plus icon on network manager GUI where my modem is detected as E173.

I don't know what log to post but I am posting some as of my knowledge.

```
lsusb 

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub   
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 
Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Modem/Networkcard
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

nmcli dev

DEVICE    TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
wlp2s0    wifi      connected    AndroidAP  
enp1s0    ethernet  unavailable  --         
ttyUSB2   gsm       unavailable  --
```

I tried to switch modem mode by reading some posts. Using usb_modeswitch but that gives error.

I tried

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1506 -V 0x12d1 -P 0x14dc -M 
"55534243123456780000000000000a11062000000000000100000000000000"
```

This gives error:

```
Look for target devices ...
No devices in target mode or class found
Look for default devices ...
product ID matched
Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 009 on bus 002
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
Use endpoints 0x02 (out) and 0x82 (in)
Error: can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0;
   interface class is 255, expected 8. Abort
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/888230/167850

Comment: does not work.. modem still got detected as E173 in gui .

Comment: can't keep up with the instruction. post some clear instruction with commands.