# 4G/LTE modem connection issue

Tags: usb-modem

I'm trying to use a Huawei 4G dongle on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

My USB 4G dongle is correctly detected as a modem :

```
romain@dPanda:~$ lsusb
...
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 12d1:1c05 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Broadband stick (modem on)
```

My problem is not a usb_modswitch issue because the modem is correctly detected as a modem by NetworkManager

I can set-up the connection with Network-Manager, but when i try to connect the connection fails.

Here is syslog extract :

```
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda NetworkManager[873]: <info>  [1521892701.1289] device (ttyUSB2): Activation: starting connection 'Free Mobile' (d91a2b28-b566-4244-b243-61642de63acb)
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda NetworkManager[873]: <info>  [1521892701.1291] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="d91a2b28-b566-4244-b243-61642de63acb" name="Free Mobile" pid=1490 uid=1000 result="success"
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda NetworkManager[873]: <info>  [1521892701.1292] device (ttyUSB2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda NetworkManager[873]: <info>  [1521892701.1296] device (ttyUSB2): state change: prepare -> need-auth (reason 'none') [40 60 0]
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda NetworkManager[873]: <info>  [1521892701.1832] device (ttyUSB2): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda ModemManager[792]: <info>  Simple connect started...
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda ModemManager[792]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda ModemManager[792]: <info>  Simple connect state (5/8): Register
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda ModemManager[792]: <info>  Simple connect state (6/8): Bearer
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda ModemManager[792]: <info>  Simple connect state (7/8): Connect
Mar 24 12:58:21 dPanda ModemManager[792]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (registered -> connecting)
Mar 24 12:58:30 dPanda ModemManager[792]: <warn>  Couldn't initialize PDP context with our APN: 'Sending command failed: 'Resource temporarily unavailable''
Mar 24 12:58:30 dPanda ModemManager[792]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connecting -> registered)
Mar 24 12:58:30 dPanda NetworkManager[873]: <warn>  [1521892710.7878] (ttyUSB2): failed to connect modem: Sending command failed: 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
Mar 24 12:58:30 dPanda NetworkManager[873]: <info>  [1521892710.7879] device (ttyUSB2): state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'unknown') [40 120 1]
Mar 24 12:58:30 dPanda NetworkManager[873]: <warn>  [1521892710.7902] device (ttyUSB2): Activation: failed for connection 'Free Mobile'
Mar 24 12:58:30 dPanda NetworkManager[873]: <info>  [1521892710.7912] device (ttyUSB2): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
```

Regards,
Romain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Huawei modem does not work with 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776497/huawei-modem-does-not-work-with-16-04)

Comment: Not really because my modem is correctly detected by network-manager